# Searching through navigation drawer list and main fragment list with Robotium on Android

Tags: android, robotium

In my Robotium test I am trying to assert that a certain text is visible in a navigation drawer. However, the same text happens to be visible behind the navigation drawer in the main content fragment. Now, if I would assert that the text is visible by using

```
solo.searchText("myText");
```

true will be always returned since the text is visible behind the navigation drawer. Using the boolean onlyVisible for searchText does not seem to change anything either, I wager that it is not meant for this kind of case.

Now, I know I could try to do some dirty hack like going through the views that are inside the navigation drawer by using

```
solo.getViews(solo.getView(R.id.menu_drawer));
```

and checking if any of those views contain the text I am looking for, but this does not seem like a reasonable thing to do.

My question would be that is it possible to reliably assert that the text is visible only in my navigation drawer using Robotium? In the API I can't really see a way to search for a text in a specific list.